# Error While Updating an Custom Address Field using flows

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, custom-object, data-types, recordtriggeredflow

Whenever the Opportunity record is created, the custom address field should be updated with the account billing address, but while being created, I'm getting the error:

```
"This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: 
INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST: Custom Address (Country/Territory): bad value for restricted picklist field: India. 
You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. 
Error ID: 256441183-69009 (1936300210)ook up"
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `Country` field is a picklist which does not contain the value `India`.

As you mentioned that it is a custom address field, it might be worthwhile to go have a look what are the values given to the `Country` field. Your org might be using the standard countries picklist (see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_state_country_picklists_standard_countries.htm&type=5)) which would mean that you should input `IN` for the country.

You can navigate to the configured picklists for `State` and `Country` by following [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_state_country_picklists_configure.htm&type=5) Salesforce help article to see exactly what is being used.

Good luck!